# Show two frames in the same window

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to design a layout like in this image

[image]

`Frame 1` is gray and he `Frame 2` is transparent. I think we need to use `FrameLayout` but I don't know exactly how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you could use a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout`(at least for the `Frame 1`) but you don't say what exactly do you want to do with those frames(this will change things a bit). I would use a `RelativeLayout` because I'm guessing you'll have content in frame 1 besides frame 2:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/frame1" android:background="#c1c1c1"// other attributes>
     <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame2" android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
      android:background="@android:color/transparent"// other attributes />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

one way can be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#c0c0c0" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make the above like screen using two frames, because it is not possible to put one frame in to the another frame layout, so you can make it by using another way like, take one relative layout and put the frame inside it like,

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
            android:background="@color/tbl_green">
        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

may be this can help you.